# Electric Field Calculations in VASP

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, electric-field

Can someone share appropriate tags and method to apply Electric Field in VASP?

Answer (score 8):

I think VASP has limited electric field ability right now, but someone may come along later and correct me.  If you have a surface in the Z direction, you could enable an electric field as such.

```
EFIELD = X # Units eV/A
IDIPOL = 3 # Z direction
LDIPOL = .TRUE. # Enable dipole corrections
```

Comment: So why is the ability "limited", maybe you could elaborate on the limitations?

Comment: It doesn't seem to allow for point charges (or I have missed it in the documentation).  The EFIELD tag is the only electric field tag I was able to find for VASP while looking over the documentation.